# Unrecognized configuration key was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I am using STS IDE and developed a quarkus project following below example
https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client

When I tried building the code using
compile quarkus:dev -DSkipTests=true command, I observed below warnings saying its unable to recognize quarkus properties, but application is started

**Console Log:**

```
2022-01-07 18:09:44,890 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.rest-client."com.scania.siddhiapi.services.SiddhiService".url" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2022-01-07 18:09:44,890 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
```

**Application.properties file:**

```
quarkus.http.port=8085 
quarkus.rest-client."com.scania.siddhiapi.services.SiddhiService".url=
logging.level.= INFO 
org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.host=
org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.port=8080
org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.scheme=http
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.scania.siddhiapi</groupId>
  <artifactId>siddhiapi_quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.3.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-lambda</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-spring-di</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

If someone has experienced anything similar, please help me with the cause I am unable to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to documentation of Quarkus and dependencies. Please add below dependency in your pom.xml. it will help to resolve issue related to quarkus.http.port property.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of Quarkus you are using does not support that configuration.

You need to use 2.5.0.Final or higher

Comment: Thankyou for the suggetsion. I tried to rebuild the code with 2.6.1.final.
One of the warnings are resolved but I could still see below warning:
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

Comment: @geoand I'm already using Quarkus 2.15.3.Final still facing the issue.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?