# Running Kogito Examples shows Warning "Unrecognized configuration keys was provided; it will be ignored"

Tags: quarkus, kie, kogito, quarkus-extension

I am running the [Process user tasks with timer: Hiring](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/main/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-usertasks-timer-quarkus-with-console#process-user-tasks-with-timer-hiring%5D) example in the `kiegroup/kogito-examples` repository. I am building and deploying with the default Infinispan profile/ configuration. My goal is to be able to use the Kogito Management Console and Task Inbox.

I followed the README and referenced the Kogito documentation here: https://docs.kogito.kie.org/latest/html_single

I was anticipating the config properties to have a modified name in the latest version, but the names look the same, so why are my configs showing up as unrecognized?

- I didn't see `quarkus.infinispan-client.hosts` in the latest docs, and saw `quarkus.infinispan-client.server-list`. But all the versions of `application.properties` for the example still used the former.

I am using the `1.44.1.Final` tag version. I compared the `quarkus-platform-version` on the different branches and noticed the main branch they are using `3.2.9.Final`, but the rest are all `2.16` so the example should be working for those versions.

Here is the [application.properties](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/1.44.1.Final/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-usertasks-timer-quarkus-with-console/src/main/resources/application.properties)

```
...
#to be reachable from the container running job-service
kogito.service.url=http://host.docker.internal:8080
kogito.dataindex.http.url=http://localhost:8180
kogito.dataindex.ws.url=ws://localhost:8180
...
#Job-service
kogito.jobs-service.url=http://localhost:8580
...
```

Here is the [pom.xml](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/1.44.1.Final/kogito-quarkus-examples/process-usertasks-timer-quarkus-with-console/pom.xml)

```xml
...
<properties>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>2.16.10.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.10.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <kogito.bom.group-id>org.kie.kogito</kogito.bom.group-id>
    <kogito.bom.artifact-id>kogito-bom</kogito.bom.artifact-id>
    <kogito.bom.version>1.44.1.Final</kogito.bom.version>
    <version.org.kie.kogito>1.44.1.Final</version.org.kie.kogito>
</properties>
...
```

The warning logs when I run `mvn clean compile quarkus:dev -PInfinispan`:

```
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "kogito.persistence.type" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "kogito.dataindex.ws.url" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "kogito.dataindex.http.url" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "kogito.jobs-service.url" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
```

Note: I saw this similar question but was not helpful or similar to my example [Unrecognized configuration key was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643760/unrecognized-configuration-key-was-provided-it-will-be-ignored-verify-that-the)

Comment: I tried using another config property in the docs that defaults to true `kogito.data-index.domain-indexing=true`, and hit the same error.
`[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "kogito.data-index.domain-indexing" was provided; it will be ignored;`